# Sequential counter which starts counting at condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table:

```
  id   market
  1    mkt1
  2    mkt2
  3    mkt1
  4    special
  5    mkt2
  6    mkt2
  7    special
```

And I want to add a sequential counter column, which starts counting once a condition has been triggered. In this example, when `market=="special"`:

```
 id   market  count
 1    mkt1     0
 2    mkt2     0
 3    mkt1     0
 4    special  1
 5    mkt2     2
 6    mkt2     3
 7    special  4
```

How can I do this? I imagine there's a simple solution, possibly using `dplyr` but I'm not sure how to word my problem concisely enough to search for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option with `cumsum` with `cummax`

```
df1$count <- cumsum(cummax(df1$market == "special"))
```

---

which can be converted in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(count  = cumsum(cummax(market == "special")))
#  id  market count
#1  1    mkt1     0
#2  2    mkt2     0
#3  3    mkt1     0
#4  4 special     1
#5  5    mkt2     2
#6  6    mkt2     3
#7  7 special     4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:7, market = c("mkt1", "mkt2", "mkt1", "special", 
"mkt2", "mkt2", "special")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
```